# Apollo GraphQL: service layer between resolvers and models

Tags: graphql, apollo

I'm new to `Apollo` and `GraphQL` in general. I have an architecture/best practice question.

Currently, my resolvers call the model layer straight but I feel the need to add a Service Layer in-between. The main reason is one of my resolvers is having many steps, including one being the logic already implemented in another resolver.

For example, `TypeA` and `TypeB`. `TypeA` entities contains 1 `TypeB` entity.
I have my resolver to create an entity `TypeB` with some logic like an autogenerated code.
I want my resolver to create an entity `TypeA` to call the creation of TypeB if needed. (e.g. the classic `Other` option in a dropdown to auto-populate a DB)

What I want to do is having the chain `resolver -> service -> model`

For `TypeB`

- My resolver will do some checks about the request (e.g. authorization) and call the service.
- My service layer will handle the autogenerated code and call the model.

For `TypeA`

- My resolver will also do some checks about the request. Then call the service about `TypeA` entities.
- This `TypeA` service has some business logic, calls the model, and will optionally call the service about `TypeB` entities.

I couldn't find much documentation about it... Is it the way to go or did I miss something else?

Comment: just microservices with graphql [one of access layer] on top?

Comment: Do you mean something like an `API Gateway` to deal with the Authentication/Authorization?
I would still need my `resolver A` to use the logic in my `resolver B`.

Or do you mean having one MicroService with the High-level logic, calling a second MicroService with kind of atomic actions?

Comment: just read about microservices (arch) forgeting about graphql top layer (resolver A calling resolver B) - how they can be separated, how tightly they are coupled, how they can communicate - auth/user is one of services

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I won't go as far as splitting my application into 2 microservices. My TypeA and TypeB are too tightly coupled. 
I am more interested in the architecture practices inside a GraphQL server. What should be done when someone is facing the need to call one resolver from another.